# Destroying the form

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection, destructor

How can I do that?

Under *destroying* I mean *remove it from the memory*.

An example (Form1 is some form):

```
static void Main()
{
    Test();
    // here we still have A alive
    // GC.Collect()  doesn't helps

    Form1 B = new Form1();
    Application.Run(B);
    // problem is here: B and A "collides", due to assumption what A is already dead
}

public static Test()
{
    Form1 A = new Form1();
    // do something with A, but not displaying form
    // I was sure what A will disappears after Test()
}
```

Could the problem be certain components used on form? Timers, which are created in constructor? Or is it a **normal** way for A to exists that long?

### Update

Collides - means they are using something what is exclusive to a single user only. How can I *push* the process of removing A from memory?

Please, do not be rushy (thanks for -2), I am at work, so can't update fast. I am trying to be as clear as I can.

Whenever you can, please avoid using cliches *GC.Collect is always bad*, etc. I know that. As you can see all I need a sort of manipulations with the form before software runs, so no performance or any other sort of issue is expected. It may be not the best case, but please then, tell me the better one. Doing something with A is a necessary test, yes.

The problem is: after doing test with A, I want it to *disappear*. Of course I can modify A in a way what it will not have timers, components, etc. But there are dozens of forms already. And all has to be tested. And I simply didn't knew that what A will exists after Test().

### Update 2

I really want to know why question has -3. What I learned today is *when you create a form, it will exists until the end of application* and there is now known way to kill it. Timers, created in constructor will keep running, components will try to access something they shouldn't, etc. Whole lots of things will changes as soon as you care to create second instance of working (as it seems) form.

### Update 3

Lets make a simple test:

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool Test { get; set; }
    static void Main()
    {
        DoTest();
        Test = true;
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void DoTest()
    {
        var A = new Form1();
        var B = new Form1();
        var C = new Form1();
        //A.Dispose();
        //B.Dispose();
        //C.Dispose();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Program.Test)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("123");
        }
    }
}
```

It will show 4 message boxes (from main window and from *undead* A, B, C). Before today I was 100% sure, what whatever I put on form will be deleted together with form. And whenever I create a local variable - it is going to be local. But it seems it is not. And this is a problem - un-obvious behavior.

It looks like Thorsten Dittmar solution with `Dispose()` should do a trick. I should look myself into my components (shutting their timers manually, etc).

Comment: What do you mean by `B and A "collides"`

Comment: Can you define "collide"? Form A will stay in memory until the GC decides otherwise. If you have lots of RAM, this could be days...

Comment: There is a lot of crazy stuff that happens under the hood when the first `Form` is created. I would not be at all surprised that multiple references to `A` are kept somewhere deep in the winforms code. I recommend you find a different way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Perhaps if you told us what that was you could get a better answer.

Comment: You can not force the GC to 'destroy' your Form. With GC.Collect() you kindly ask the GC if he would be so nice to free the memory but it is his decision when he does so.

Comment: `GC.Collect()` is almost always a mistake.

Comment: By the way. If you are doing something with Form A without displaying it and then run Application.Run(B) you have a serious design problem. Or is this just some kind of test?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Dispose() has nothing to do with memory

Comment: @SriramSakthivel True, but the OP hasn't really explain what the heck his problem actually is, only that they "collide" (whatever that means).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Next option is to closure when no reply from OP about what he asks:)

Comment: @user1567896 I suppose the form `A` implements some tool method he wants to call and the easiest way is to create an instance of `A` likeit was a normal class.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, kind of. I need form instance to do my tests.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, example, component which is simply logging its data, which is put on `Form1`. When `A` is created - it will start logging. When `Test()` finished.. it continue logging. When `B` is created there will be 2 loggers simultaneously. Of course I can create `Start` method for the component and call it in `OnShow`, but there was an assumption (wrong one?) when form is disposed - everything is disposed as well. But it's not. Component is still logging (by using `Timer`, which is expected to die together with form), form is perfectly exists as *undead*. Scary shift.

Comment: The *What I've learnt today* section you wrote above is plain wrong. If you properly stop your timers in your `Dispose` method, this is simply not true. Also, forms will not exist until the end of the application's lifetime if you dispose of them properly. Of course a form (and any other class) will stay alive if any component inside is still alive keeping a reference to the object. In this case, a running timer will keep the form alive, which you can easily prevent starting the timer in `OnShow` instead of the constructor or `OnLoad`.

Comment: *there is now known way to kill it* is so wrong! You have to shutdown things properly! The known way is: do things the right way! One example: If you start a timer in the constructor, you have to stop it in `Dispose`. When you start a timer in any of the form's events, you have to stop it in `FormClose` (or latest in `Dispose`).

Comment: I have given enough time to GC to know that it need an EXPLICIT `MyObject = null;` to actually work properly. `Dispose();` is not enough but still need to call if you have the implementation on the object. Took me over 2 years figuring out how to clean Crystal Report enormous memory leaks.

Comment: Wrong, @Franck. Setting `MyObject = null;` has no effect on object disposal. Calling `Dispose` is enough and *the only way* to dispose of an object.

Comment: @Franck Of course, if you're holding a reference to an object forever, the object will not be automatically disposed of. But if you call `Dispose` on a disposable object, it will be disposed of no matter whether you set the reference to `null` or not.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Was referring or memory clean. Crystal report when you get close to it's limits which is around 75 sub reports with 75 sections each well running a dozen of them fill around 1.5-2 gig ram. You can dispose all you want and think whatever you want, if you `Dispose();` the ram is still taken and that is a fact. Setting a simple `ReportDocument = null;` clear over 90% of that ram that was taken. The object stop taking ram from there.

Comment: @Franck And this is where you're wrong. `Dispose()` does not "free RAM". It allows an object to close its resources - the object's implementation is responsible for doing this. It does *not destroy* an object (in the sense of freeing its memory). Setting an object variable to `null` has no (*zero*! *zilch*!!) effect on that. The object continues to live as long as it thinks wants. For example if an object creates a thread/timer that runs forever, the object will continue to exist no matter how often you set its reference to `null`. That's a fact. So either you're doing it wrong or Crystal.

Comment: Read my first comment. I still believe that is what is happening. Many of the things in Forms use the underlying Win32 API which requires a window handle. The first Form object created fulfills this. You should redesign your code to not need this first, false form like you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Dispose()`. Even if that doesn't mean all memory gets freed immediately, all resources opened by the form (timers, files, etc.) should be closed then, if the form is programmed properly.

Of course, the form will also be disposed of automatically when the GC runs the next time, but you can make it "disappear" manually by calling `Dispose()` yourself. Then the GC will run when it feels like running and take care of the memory, but other resources occupied by the window should be released.

The easiest way to do this is:

```
public static Test() {
    using (Form1 A = new Form1()) {
        // do something with A, but not displaying form
        // I was sure what A will disappears after Test() 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried calling `A.Dispose()` and now some of test methods fails with `FindForm().Handle` (because `FindForm()` returns null), still timers are continue running and B is colliding with A.

Comment: It looks so far, what the only *right solution* is to redesign all forms (so they don't create timers and do not attempt to do other things). If I would know that from the start ><

Comment: Maybe you're calling `Dispose` in the wrong place? Also, it could be that a form's handle is not created unless you request for it to be displayed using `Show`.

Comment: The only answer, but seems to be in the right direction.