# Custom control and dispose

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, dispose

The start of story is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067353/destroying-the-form).

I have a component and I want it to *clean* up timers (managed resources, right?):

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer1 = new Timer();
    private Timer _timer2 = new Timer();
    public MyPictureBox(): base()
    {
        _timer1.Interval = 100;
        _timer1.Start();
        _timer2.Interval = 250;
        _timer2.Start();
    }

    // ... all sort of code


    new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
        _timer1.Dispose();
        _timer2.Dispose();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _timer1.Dispose();
        _timer2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to implement one more (oO) `IdDisposable` (despite PictureBox->Control->Component->IDisposable). But.. none of them is called.

Control is put on form by using designer. But it is doesn't appears in form `Components` and this should be the reason why it is not called when form is disposed:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Dispose(); // MyPictureBox.Dispose() are not called
```

My question is how should I organize disposing of my control timers to have what I needed - disposing of MyPictureBox timers together with form disposing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to override `Dispose(bool disposing)`. and no need to explicitly implement `IDisposable`.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    _timer1.Dispose();
    _timer2.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Works like a miracle. Fast and clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: If you are using sth like UserControls, the 'protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)' Method already exists in the *.designer.cs file. Feel free to move it to *.cs file, its not in the 'Component Designer generated code' region of the designer file.

Answer (score 4):

Although Sriram's answer is correct, if you are using unmanaged types, such as COM objects, you should use the Finalizer pattern:

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer1 = new Timer();
    private Timer _timer2 = new Timer()

    //more of your stuff 

    ~MyPictureBox ()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
         //clean up unmanaged here

        if(disposing)
        {
            _timer1.Dispose();
            _timer2.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

See Dispose Pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As you are using a PictureBox, keep in mind that must Image types are `IDisposable` as well.